# Unable to access Images in xslt in AWS Lambda

Tags: xslt, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a PDF from JSON using Apache POF using Java. The xslt file is unable to acess images placed inside the JAR.

I tried using an http url and it works fine but even when I place the image in S3 and make it public, lambda is unable to access it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'lambda unable to access it'? Are you getting a permission issue or path issue?

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it failed. This is all much too vague.